# XML to C# class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Can anyone give me some advice?
An API I'm consulting generates a pattern like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ChatXMLResult>
    <Generator>AppServer.network.lcpdfr.com</Generator>
    <Version>1000</Version>
    <Time>1305910998</Time>
    <Signature>a0f1f6bea66f75de574babd242e68c47</Signature>
    <FilteredResultSet>1</FilteredResultSet>
    <Messages>
        <Message>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <UID>9</UID>
            <DisplayName>Jay</DisplayName>
            <UserName>jaymac407</UserName>
            <Time>1305900497</Time>
            <Area>Masterson St</Area>
            <Message>Test</Message>
            <TargettedMessage>false</TargettedMessage>
            <Targets>
                <Target>#Global Chat#</Target>
            </Targets>
            <Signature>1cfdff1aaa520348d0a62c87ae9717d3</Signature>
        </Message>
    </Messages>
</ChatXMLResult>
```

How can I get all messages from this in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Attributes that control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx), e.g.:

```
[XmlRoot("ChatXMLResult")] 
public class Chat
{
    [XmlElement("Signature")] // optional 
    public string Signature { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Message), ElementName="Message")]
    public Message[] Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message { .. }
```

etc

---

Also I see the common element, `<Signature />`, thus you can introduce a parent class:

```
public abstract class SignedObject
{
    public string Signature { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Linq to XML to load the xml into anonymous objects, or you could create an object to load with the values.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var messages = from m in doc.Descendants("Message")
    select new {
        ID = (string)m.Element("ID"),
        UID = (string)m.Element("UID"),
        DisplayName = (string)m.Element("DisplayName"),
        // etc
        Signature = (string)m.Element("Signature")
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization