# Using XMLSerializer deserialise with array of elements the same type as the root element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, mono, xml-deserialization

I've got the following XML i'm trying to deserialise with XmlSerialiser:

```
<playlist>
  <id>43712</id>
  <title>Eleven | Eleven</title>
  <description>Eleven</description>
  <creationDate>2010-12-01T17:54:44</creationDate>
  <lastModifiedDate>2011-05-27T01:32:58</lastModifiedDate>
  <status>ACTIVE</status>
  <syndicatedPartners/>
  <mediaList/>
  <childPlaylists>
    <playlist>
      <id>43781</id>
      <title>TV Shows | TV Shows</title>
      <description></description>
      <creationDate>2010-12-10T16:37:00</creationDate>
      <lastModifiedDate>2011-05-09T06:03:09</lastModifiedDate>
      <status>ACTIVE</status>
      <syndicatedPartners/>
      <imagePath>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/43781/</imagePath>
      <defaultImage>
        <url>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/43781/96x128.png</url>
        <height>128</height>
        <width>96</width>
      </defaultImage>
    </playlist>
    <playlist>
      <id>43787</id>
      <title>Movies | Movies</title>
      <description></description>
      <creationDate>2010-12-10T16:49:13</creationDate>
      <lastModifiedDate>2011-05-06T01:39:23</lastModifiedDate>
      <status>ACTIVE</status>
      <syndicatedPartners/>
      <imagePath>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/43787/</imagePath>
      <defaultImage>
        <url>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/43787/96x128.png</url>
        <height>128</height>
        <width>96</width>
      </defaultImage>
    </playlist>
    <playlist>
      <id>44020</id>
      <title>Eleven | This Week On Eleven</title>
      <description></description>
      <creationDate>2011-01-05T08:17:09</creationDate>
      <lastModifiedDate>2011-05-30T08:47:13</lastModifiedDate>
      <status>ACTIVE</status>
      <syndicatedPartners/>
      <imagePath>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/44020/</imagePath>
      <defaultImage>
        <url>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/44020/96x128.png</url>
        <height>128</height>
        <width>96</width>
      </defaultImage>
    </playlist>
    <playlist>
      <id>44758</id>
      <title>Fashion | Australian Fashion Week</title>
      <description></description>
      <creationDate>2011-04-28T23:58:01</creationDate>
      <lastModifiedDate>2011-05-06T05:48:22</lastModifiedDate>
      <status>ACTIVE</status>
      <syndicatedPartners/>
      <imagePath>http://media.movideo.com/images/140/playlist/44758/</imagePath>
      <defaultImage>
        <url>http://media.movideo.com/images/140/playlist/44758/96x128.png</url>
        <height>128</height>
        <width>96</width>
      </defaultImage>
    </playlist>
  </childPlaylists>
  <imagePath>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/43712/</imagePath>
  <defaultImage>
    <url>http://media.movideo.com/images/112/playlist/43712/96x128.png</url>
    <height>128</height>
    <width>96</width>
  </defaultImage>
</playlist>
```

In my C# code, I have:

```
public class Response
{
    public bool success;
    public string responseType;
}

[XmlRootAttribute("playlist", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)] 
public class PlaylistResponse : Response
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public List<PlaylistResponse> childPlaylists;
}

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlaylistResponse));
PlaylistResponse response = (PlaylistResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
state.callback((Response) response, state.data);
```

but childPlaylist seems to always be empty.

What is the correct way of deserialising this sort of XML, specifically with multiple "childPlaylists"?

Thanks.

Comment: btw, as far as I could see in XML serialization codes, you need to use arrays, not lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075343/xml-to-c-class/6075395#6075395).

---

```
[XmlRootAttribute("playlist")]
public class PlaylistResponse 
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public string description;

    [XmlArray(ElementName="childPlaylists")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(PlaylistResponse), ElementName="playlist")]
    public PlaylistResponse[] ChildPlaylists;
}

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)); // your xml above
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlaylistResponse));
PlaylistResponse response = (PlaylistResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

int count = response.ChildPlaylists.Length; // 4
```

Comment: I tried to copy the correct code, but it didn't work. I think my problem is that it's trying to refer to itself which is the root element, and I'm not specifying that it can be both a root and sub-element properly.

Comment: I keep getting "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying response.ChildPlaylists.Length

Comment: @Adam: Then you're getting and error. Strange. Works for me. Try [the previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6185666/revisions) of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You marked PlaylistResponse as root element only with XmlRootAttribute. Add XmlElementAttribute as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what the XmlRootAttribute does or how it works... Could you provide an example of where I can place XmlElementAttribute?

Comment: XmlRootAttribute("playlist") means: unmarshal **root** element named 'playlist' to this class. While unmarshalling child playlist it just cannot map this 'playlist' element to a class. Place attribute right after XmlRootAttribute)

Comment: Placing [XmlElementAttribute("playlist")] produces "Attribute not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on `property, indexer, field, parameter, return' declartaions only".

Answer (score 0):

Add the XmlArrayItem attribute to name the element names and XmlRoot to specify the name of the root element:

```
[XmlRoot("playlist")] 
public class PlaylistResponse : Response
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    [XmlArrayItem("playlist")]
    public List<PlaylistResponse> childPlaylists;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I tried with both a List<> and array, as well as the lowercase "playlist" and [XmlArray] but still the result is a count of 0 items.

Comment: fixed case typo: playList => playlist in the XmlArrayItem attribute.